# Showing every planar graph on $n$ vertices has a vertex-cover of size at most $\frac{3n}{4}$ and an independent set of size at least $\frac{n}{4}$

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, planar-graphs

> $\text{Which of the following statements is true for every planar graph on $n$ vertices?}$
>
> 1. $\text{ The graph is connected}$
> 2. $\text{ The graph is Eulerian}$
> 3. $\text{ The graph has a vertex-cover of size at most $\frac{3n}{4}$}$
> 4. $\text{ The graph has an independent set of size at least $\frac{n}{3}$}$
>    $$\tag {GATE CS 2008}$$

Clearly options 1 and 2 are wrong. I made an attempt to check the correctness of option 3 and 4.

$\alpha(G) : \text{Independence Number of G}$

$\beta(G) : \text{Minimum vertex cover of G}$

$n(G): \text{Number of vertices of G}$

$\chi(G): \text{Chromatic Number of G}$

We know,

$$\alpha(G)+\beta(G)=n(G) \tag 1$$

We also know from $\text{Four color theorem}$,

For a planar graph, $$\chi(G) \leq 4 \tag 2$$

Now we also know that,

$$\frac{n(G)}{\alpha(G)}\leq \chi(G)\tag 3$$

From $(2)$ and $(3)$ we have,

$$\frac{n(G)}{\alpha(G)}\leq \chi(G) \leq 4 \implies \frac{n(G)}{\alpha(G)} \leq 4 \implies \alpha(G)\geq \frac{n(G)}{4} = 0.25 \times n(G) \tag 4$$

Adding $\beta(G)$ to both sides of $(4)$, we have,

$$\alpha(G)+\beta(G)\geq \frac{n(G)}{4} + \beta(G)$$

But from $(1)$, we have

$$n(G)\geq \frac{n(G)}{4} + \beta(G) \implies \beta(G)\leq \frac{3n}{4} \tag 5$$

---

But to show that graph has an independent set of size at least $\frac{n}{4}$, we should try to show that the minimum size of the independent set is at least $\frac{n}{4}$ but I have shown it for $\alpha(G)$ which is the maximum size of the independent set.

Also to show that $G$ has a vertex-cover of size at most $\frac{3n}{4}$ I guess I need to show that the maximum vertex cover is at most $\frac{3n}{4}$, but what I have shown is the bound for $\beta(G)$ which the minimum vertex cover.

I am kind of stuck. How to proceed. Please guide. Thank you.

Comment: The equation $\alpha(G)+\beta(G)=n(G)$ means that statement 4 is equivalent to $\beta(G) \le \frac23 n(G)$ which is strictly stronger than statement 3. So without knowing anything about planar graphs, we can eliminate it :)

Comment: @MishaLavrov But for that I guess one needs to know that statement 3 is correct. But if one does not know definitely about statements 3 and 4 then he has to first work with statement 3 (check that it is fine) and then work with statement 4 as you said. Am I right?

Comment: I mean that if you know in advance that exactly one of the statements is correct (but not which one), then you can eliminate statement 4, because if statement 4 were correct, statement 3 would also be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Four-colour the graph. The vertices with the three rarest colours are a covering set.

Comment: I just noted that you essentaily arrived at that, i.e.,m $\beta(G)\le\frac 34 n$. This precisely states that there exists a vertex cove of size at most $\frac 34n$. Your final remarrk indicates that you seem to misinterpret the statement 3

Comment: hmm, now I got it. I was misinterpreting it. In mind something like "for all vertex cover" was going on. Since it is given as "has a vertex cover"... it is in the "there exists" sense. So if I get minimum vertex cover of size at most $\frac{3n}{4}$ , I actually have a vertex "a vertex cover" with size at most $\frac{3n}{4}$